# How can I access Box periodically from a server, starting with a Developer Token?

Tags: box

This is basically the same question as [How to get an access token without Box’s authorization page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613359/how-to-get-an-access-token-without-box-s-authorization-page).  I see that the Python package mentioned at the end (box.py) is no longer maintained because of support issues with Box.  I suspect the solutions given might no longer work.

I'm just getting started with boxsdk and I want a way to periodically list the contents of my folder without requiring user interaction.  This looks like the answer but it also seems very odd that a Developer Token, which is temporary, could be used for long-term queries like this.

I'm trying to work through boxsdk to see how I can implement the solution provided in 2014 but it would sure help to know whether or not it's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this:
[Introducing Developer Tokens](https://blog.box.com/blog/introducing-developer-tokens/)
"There is no refresh token paired with the token"

That's from February 18, 2014.